# RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: anaconda, runtime, gpu, pytorch

CUDA error with pytorch

Installed pytorch with conda and CUDA support

The error occurs when I am trying to run a tensor on the cuda gpu

```
torch.rand(10).to(torch.device('cuda'))

RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in call(self, obj)
700 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
701 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702 printer.pretty(obj)
703 printer.flush()
704 return stream.getvalue()

~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
397 if cls is not object
398 and callable(cls.dict.get('repr')):
--> 399 return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
400
401 return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.py in repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
687 """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
688 # Find newlines and replace them with p.break()
--> 689 output = repr(obj)
690 for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
691 if idx:

~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in repr(self)
128 # characters to replace unicode characters with.
129 if sys.version_info > (3,):
--> 130 return torch._tensor_str._str(self)
131 else:
132 if hasattr(sys.stdout, 'encoding'):

~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in _str(self)
309 tensor_str = _tensor_str(self.to_dense(), indent)
310 else:
--> 311 tensor_str = _tensor_str(self, indent)
312
313 if self.layout != torch.strided:

~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in _tensor_str(self, indent)
207 if self.dtype is torch.float16 or self.dtype is torch.bfloat16:
208 self = self.float()
--> 209 formatter = _Formatter(get_summarized_data(self) if summarize else self)
210 return _tensor_str_with_formatter(self, indent, formatter, summarize)
211

~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in init(self, tensor)
85
86 else:
---> 87 nonzero_finite_vals = torch.masked_select(tensor_view, torch.isfinite(tensor_view) & tensor_view.ne(0))
88
89 if nonzero_finite_vals.numel() == 0:

~/anaconda3/envs/deep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/functional.py in isfinite(tensor)
225 if not tensor.is_floating_point():
226 return torch.ones_like(tensor, dtype=torch.bool)
--> 227 return (tensor == tensor) & (tensor.abs() != inf)
228
229

RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

This is the collect_env.py output:

Collecting environment information...

PyTorch version: 1.3.1

Is debug build: No

CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.0.130

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

GCC version: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609

CMake version: version 3.5.1

Python version: 3.7

Is CUDA available: Yes

CUDA runtime version: 10.0.130

GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: GeForce 920M

Nvidia driver version: 415.27

cuDNN version: Could not collect

Versions of relevant libraries:

[pip] numpy==1.17.4

[pip] numpy-stl==2.10.1

[pip] torch==1.3.1

[pip] torchvision==0.4.2

[conda] blas 1.0 mkl

[conda] mkl 2019.4 243

[conda] mkl-service 2.3.0 py37he904b0f_0

[conda] mkl_fft 1.0.15 py37ha843d7b_0

[conda] mkl_random 1.1.0 py37hd6b4f25_0

[conda] pytorch 1.3.1 py3.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.6.3_0 pytorch

[conda] torchvision 0.4.2 py37_cu100 pytorch

Some have stated that the TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST needs to be manually set to ='3.5', but I can't figure out how

Comment: You can set it as `export TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="3.5"` in terminal.